# MySQL InnoDB Same Select another result

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using InnoDB on MySQL and I have problem with selecting data from log

when I select

```
SELECT * FROM `log` 
WHERE `updated` >= '20140110144000' AND `updated` <= '20140110150000' 
ORDER BY `updated` ASC
```

I will get two different result

in execution at time 15:00
will get 0 rows

in execution at time 16:00
will get over 2.000 rows

how is it possible ? innodb memory cache ?

Comment: @SamD That has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB vs. MyISAM are different database engines. Look here for a good detailed explanation.

[Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-estimated-rows-count-is-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-result/11926300#11926300)

Answer (score 1):

sorry solved

I have corrupted NTP synchronization... and other server and data to log with older datetime

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `log` 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(`updated`) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('20140110144000') AND TIMESTAMP('20140110150000') 
ORDER BY `updated` ASC
```