# Different Number of Row counts?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I just created a table and ran a program which should add 170,256 rows.Then I checked the number of rows using PHP MyAdmin GUI. Below is the image.

[image]

According to the "Rows" column, I got only 162,230 rows! Then I ran the below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `key_hash`
```

This generated the below result, which should be correct.

---

[image]

---

So my question is, how come the same thing display 2 different values? How should I know which is correct?

Comment: I think the key piece of information is right in front of you, namely "~"

Comment: If you run show table status from mydb like 'mytable' then it shows you estimated row count instead of exact rows..so php myadmin is using this to showing count of rows while sqlyog show exact rows. So to avoid this confusion you can use sqlyog instead of php myadmin...just for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `key_hash`
```

provides you with exact row count.

What you see in summary (162,230) is just estimation (hence `~` sign)

Here is more detailed explaination

[Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results)