# Update anomaly. Mysql sql different rows affected count

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `attempts` WHERE date = '27-04-2014' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This particular query gave **386 results**(PHPmyAdmin) but on executing the below query

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET points = points *2 WHERE date = '27-04-2014'
```

I got **379 rows affected.** . Shouldn't I get same numbers? Any other reasons possible? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query won't affect the rows where `points = 0`, because doubling the value of points won't have any effect.

For example, try running this query:

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET points = points + 0 WHERE date = '27-04-2014'
```

and it will show **0 rows affected**.

Also, the count shown by [phpMyAdmin is an estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results), if you're using InnoDB. Use `COUNT(*)` to get the exact count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `attempts` WHERE date = '27-04-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

"Affected rows" counts only rows that were changed. If you have records with 0 points, doubling the number of points has no effect and these records will not be included in the count.