# mysql number of rows mismatch in phpmyadmin and query

Tags: php, sql

I am facing issue in figure out the number of rows in mysql table 'users'.

Number of rows when browse the table is different then number of rows when fire SQL query to count(*) from table.

Screenshot :

[image]

but when i fire following query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
```

It is giving me different number of rows

Screenshot is of different database, in actual database records are 7,40,215 and in count query it is 16,12,145

Please help me out to figure this issue out.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?

Comment: I am using MYSQL DB

Comment: Then you aren't querying the same table.  @DarshanJain the engine should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Then how the query is returning different number of rows then the number of rows in phpmyadmin

Comment: The `~` before the 3694 shows it is an approximate figure.

Comment: InnoDB tables do not keep track of how many rows the table contains and at the other end, phpMyAdmin uses a query like SHOW TABLE STATUS to get an estimated count of the number of rows in the table from the engine (InnoDB) @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Try adding dbname.tablename in the query. select count(*) from yourdbname.users

Comment: Yes, it shows approximate figure, but still the difference is like twice

Comment: It's easy enough to find out whether it's the same table, I would think? Add/update a record in one and then look for it in the other?

Comment: You could do 'drop table' to see if it's the same table?  Just kidding don't do that.

Comment: @DarshanJain Then I recant what I said.  I thought the OP was using `SELECT COUNT(*)` in both places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results)

Comment: How many rows u have in phpmyadmib page? Is it around more than 25 or 30?

Comment: Why don't you just execute the query in PHPmyAdmin.  It's not hard to do.