# Number of rows are different in MySQL show total and count query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting confused with the number of rows in MySQL. The total rows returned by phpMyAdmin and the count query are different.

My table structure is `InnoDB`.

```
Showing rows 0 - 24 (655537 total, Query took 0.1527 seconds.)
```

This is result of When browse the Table.

My count query was

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `table_name`
```

This will be return as `602030`

[image]

Comment: Are you implementing this in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @TeeKea yes you are right.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you browse using a tool, like phpmyadmin or heidiSQL, a query like this is executed:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table';
```

this value is inaccurate and if you run it many times, it always gives different results.

on the contrary the query:

```
select count(*) from table
```

is actually counting the records, and gives a correct result.

As mentioned in mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html:

> Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
>   exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
>   an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40%
>   to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
>   count.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql said: by INNODb the total is just approximation of the count.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html