# Select query showing less row and distinct, count showing more rows

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am getting the wrong result from Distinct query.

I have trying to get result from column where distinct values but while I am running query

```
select distict(column_name) from tbl_name;
```

Getting output :  241091

While I am running :

```
select * from tbl_name;
```

getting output : 240469

the output changed.

If I run

```
select count(*) from tbl_name;
```

getting output : 241091

Please do help why output varies.

expected result total no of rows distinct showing more value

Comment: Phpmyadmin is showing a number wich can be not exact. The count is the good value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results

Answer (score 0):

This query: `select count(*) from tbl_name;` gives you the exact count of the rows in the table.

The number you're seeing when you run this one: `select * from tbl_name;` is an approximation.

The accepted answer to this question has more details: [Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results)