# PHPMyAdmin - backing up - How to ensure I am getting All of the Table Rows Accurately?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am backing up some large tables, and moving them to another server, to work on a mirror application.
When downloading the tables I notice - sometimes - I am getting a different number of rows for the same table!

I am using PHPMyAdmin's export feature:

**PHPMyAdmin->Select_TABLE->EXPORT->SAVE_AS_FILE->My_Table.sql**
Compression->none.

**PROBLEM:** It is producing an inconsistent number of rows in the downloaded file.

10 separate exports of the same table:

1. ROW COUNT: 93788
2. ROW COUNT: 93788
3. ROW COUNT: 92465
4. ROW COUNT: 90879
5. ROW COUNT: 92691
6. ROW COUNT: 93788
7. ROW COUNT: 93788
8. ROW COUNT: 93788
9. ROW COUNT: 93788
10. ROW COUNT: 93788

---

Obviously I would take the most consistent result - but:

- What is the guaranteed method to ensure I get all the rows accurately?
- How do I make an accurate comparison if the row count is different each time?

Comment: what code or command are you running to produce that output? whats it got to do with phpmyadmin? whats not working? Did you see/read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results

Comment: I am using PHPMyAdmin's export feature.
PHPMyAdmin->Select_TABLE->EXPORT->SAVE_AS->My_Table.sql

Comment: With large files, I suggest using the `mysqldump` utility rather than the phpMyAdmin export feature. Using phpMyAdmin is subject to resource limits such as memory or execution time, and it's usually better to use the `mysqldump` utility because of those. Ideally, phpMyAdmin can keep track of what's been exported and pick up where it left off to work around the limits, but apparently that's not working in this case. As Mahdi mentions, you can also split your export if you're having trouble with the export as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a compression like zipped or gzipped?

you can also split your result to smaller chunks if there is some limit in your server. for doing this you need to check Dump some row(s) and fill the inputs.