# Showing wrong total data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a tables in my flight database. where actually has 114 records. but in the query result message of phpmyadmin it showing 144285 records. But when I use the `COUNT()` aggregate function to count the data then it's showing actual amount of data.
When I click on the table then showing below text
`Showing rows 0 - 24 (144285 total, Query took 0.0005 seconds.)`
But If I use `COUNT(*)` then showing right total
I add the code which is i run
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` flight_positions`

I want to know that why actually it's happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results)

Comment: You can execute `ANALYZE TABLE flight_positions` to trigger an update of the table statistics but they will still be an estimate.