# mysql select & count do not match, rogue script?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am using php to import rows from a large .txt file to mysql on a shared server. I created the structure of mysql in advance to match the .txt format and added an id with auto increment.

The mysql file was updated.
However, the program timed out and the results are troubling.

Using phpMyAdmin:

1. the last id is 161,867.
2. “SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_sql_file” is 161,867.
3. “SELECT * FROM my_sql_file” is 155,737.

Further more, after checking these results several times over the course of several hours, results #1 & 2 remained at their original number. However, result #3 kept changing. Sometimes the total would be higher, sometimes lower.

Tech support suspected a rogue script updating the file.
I did not sanitize the data before writing to mysql.
Could a script in the data be the problem? Is there any other explanation?

No errors were in the error log. The results were different by 10s of 1000s, and continued to change after the process ended.

Comment: Do you mean for #3 the "row count" in your query results?

Comment: How did you load in the data? What does "I did not sanitize the data before writing to mysql" mean?

Comment: @tadman #3 row count - When I ran the Select in phpMyAdmin (SQL tab). I loaded the data using php IMPORT.  "Sanitizing" is a wordpress recommendation when using data from an outside source. https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/sanitizing/
The answer to my question is in the link above and comment below. It has to do with mySql and the InnoDB engine which "estimates" the number of records.  Who knew?

Answer (score 1):

This happens in phpmyadmin you should rely on:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_sql_file” is 161,867.
```

Quoting from [Why is the estimated rows count very different in phpmyadmin results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results)

> phpMyAdmin uses a query like SHOW TABLE STATUS to get an estimated count of the number of rows in the table from the engine (InnoDB). Since it's just an estimate, it varies each time you call it, sometimes the variations can be fairly large, and sometimes they are close.

Comment: If you think that this question is a duplicate of the other, please flag it as such instead of posting an answer

Comment: actually i have just started using stack overflow to answer so i am not fully aware